# c++ compatibility of parameters with ref issues

Tags: c++, vector

i am currently programming a c++ matrix with templates.
i have a vector constructor, that gets number of rows, number of cols, and
one long vector which is (num-of-cols*num-of-rows) long.

this is the current constructor code:

```
Matrix<T>(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols, const vector<T>&cells)
{
    this->rowsNum = rows;
    this->colsNum = cols;

    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < colsNum; k++)
        {
            this->mat[i][k] = cells[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

}
```

this is me calling the function from main:

```
int main()
{
    const vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    Matrix<int> m {1, 5, v};
    cout << m << endl;

}
```

every time i run it, the program crush in the middle of the constructor,
in the line:

```
this->mat[i][k] = cells[j];
```

the debugger also show me the c++ page "stl_vector.h", in those lines:

```
  reference
  operator[](size_type __n) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
```

I have no idea what to do. I believe it's const and ref compatibility, but
i have no idea whats wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the matrix, a vector of vectors of  <T>.

Comment: UPDATE: that was the problem, i forgot to resize mat.

Comment: `ASSERT(rows * cols == cells.size())`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `resize` your variable `mat` (if it is a `vector`) or `new` to the correct `row` and `cols` size. You cannot assign to those indexes in `mat` if that memory has not yet been allocated.